# devise how to sign in a user after post from external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `form` on an `site1.com` that `POST` a devise user object to `site2.com/users`.

It works but the user is not signed in. I see it may be related because there's no CSRF token on the form on `site1.com`.

I'm a bit lost in how to solve this. Should I do an ajax call from `site1.com` to `site2.com` before the POST just to retrieve the CSRF? Any idea what would be a preferred way  to do this?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your site2 if it supports, you can post JSON over http
something like this
    {"username": "", "password": "password", "application": ""}

it will be up to your second site how it processes.

Comment: I do not see how your answer is related to my question?